# Laravel-5.8: route show don't return any values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

In previous versions of Laravel I was using something like this in controller in show function

```php
Route::resource( 'our-project', 'ProjectController' );

public function show( Project $project ) {
        return view( 'portalComponents.projects.projectDetails', compact( 'project' ) );
}
```

I was trying the same in laravel 5.8 but the `$project` attributes comes empty.

Comment: In addition to @MaartenDev perfect answer you can define the name of the parameter used with the `parameters()` function, i.e.: `Route::resource( 'our-project', 'ProjectController' )->parameters(['our-project' => 'project']);`

Comment: @dparoli thanks please add as answer it may helps others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Route model binding won't work for `our-project/1` because laravel can't infer the model. It tries to bind the `our-project` placeholder to a variable that has the name name in the `show` method. That argument doesn't exist. Because if this the `$project` variable stays empty.

the following resource would work:

```
Route::resource( 'projects', 'ProjectController' );
```

because this uses the `project` placeholder in routes. Check the output from `php artisan route:list`

It is also possible to have the same resource with different prefixes:

```
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
});
```

the first one is `/projects/1` and the second one is `/admin/projects/`

Comment: Thanks this worked fine. still one more question here can I have two `routes` with the same name but different `prefix` like `Route::group(
    [ 'prefix' => 'admin' ],
    function () {Route::resource( 'projects', 'ProjectController' );} );` and `Route::resource( 'project', 'ProjectController' );` in another word is this right practice

Comment: Yes, that perfectly fine and possible! Checkout the latest edit :) @YousefAltaf

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completness and as alternative to @MaartenDev right answer, if you want to define the name of the *parameter* used with a *resource route* you can use the `parameters()` function, i.e.:

```php
Route::resource( 'our-project', 'ProjectController' )
    ->parameters(['our-project' => 'project']);
```